# Word Count using AWK

Tags: awk

I have file like below :

this is a sample file
this file will be used for testing

```
this is a sample file
this file will be used for testing
```

I want to count the words using AWK.

the expected output is

```
this 2
is 1
a 1
sample 1
file 2
will 1
be 1
used 1
for 1
```

the below AWK I have written but getting some errors

```
cat anyfile.txt|awk -F" "'{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}'
```

Comment: What errors are you getting, specifically?

Comment: Can your file contain punctuation (`. , ' ? ! -` etc.)?

Comment: @EdMorton I see now why you asked this question. I tried the code with text with punctuation and it lists `this` and `this?` or `this,` as different words. How can I fix this so that it skips the punctuation?

Comment: @zeynel please ask a new question.

Comment: @EdMorton I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677997/how-to-remove-punctuation-marks-using-awk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works fine for me:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' testfile
used 1
this 2
be 1
a 1
for 1
testing 1
file 2
will 1
sample 1
is 1
```

PS you do not need to set `-F" "`, since its default any blank.
PS2, do not use `cat` with programs that can read data itself, like `awk`

You can add `sort` behind code to sort it.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' testfile | sort -k 2 -n
a 1
be 1
for 1
is 1
sample 1
testing 1
used 1
will 1
file 2
this 2
```

Comment: It works after removing the field separator option. But I didn't get what problem the -F" " was causing? Could you please help me understand

Comment: I'm guessing that in your original input there are a different number or type of whitespace characters between the two columns. The default behaviour of awk is to work with one or more of any type of space, whereas you specified only a single space.

Comment: @TomFenech specifying a single space would make zero difference to awk since that IS the default value of FS, it's just internally awk behaves "specially" if FS is a single space. For a LITERAL single space you need `FS="[ ]"`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping each line and saving the word in array (`{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++}`) use gawk with multi-char RS (**R**ecord **S**eparator) definition support option and save each field in array as following(It's a little bit fast):

```
gawk '{a[$0]++} END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}' RS='[[:space:]]+' file
```

Output:

```
used 1
this 2
be 1
a 1
for 1
testing 1
file 2
will 1
sample 1
is 1
```

In above gawk command I defines space-character-class `[[:space:]]+` (including one or more spaces or `\n`ew line character) as record separator.

Comment: Nice idea but you should state that it is gawk-specific due to multi-char RS and you should use `RS='[[:space:]]+'` instead of hard-coding just those 2 space chars.

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need `|\n` though as `[[:space:]]` represents all white space characters including `\n`.

Comment: updated. thanks again. If I miss something else feel free to improve :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Perl code which provides similar sorted output to Jotne's awk solution:

`perl -ne 'for (split /\s+/, $_){ $w{$_}++ }; END{ for $key (sort keys %w) { print "$key $w{$key}\n"}}' testfile`

`$_` is the current line, which is split based on whitespace `/\s+/`
Each word is then put into `$_`
The `%w` hash stores the number of occurrences of each word
After the entire file is processed, the `END{}` block is run
The keys of the `%w` hash are sorted alphabetically
Each word `$key` and number of occurrences `$w{$key}` is printed