# How to remove punctuation marks using awk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I need a command line in shell that given a text file "novel" displays in a single line each word along with the number of line it corresponds, writing it in a file called "words". The problem is the words can't have punctuation marks.
This is what I have

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {printf $i "\t" NR "\n", $0 > "words"}}' novel
```

The file contains:

```
$ cat novel 
ver a don Quijote, y ellas le defendían la puerta:
-¿Qué quiere este mostrenco en esta casa?
```

Expected output:

```
ver 1
a 1
don 1
Quijote 1
...
puerta 1
Qué 2
...
casa 2
```

It's a very simple command for academic use.

Comment: Could you give us some sample of your input files and expected output? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using awk

Try this command:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} 1' RS='[[:space:]]' novel >words
```

As an example, consider this file:

```
$ cat novel
It was a "dark" and stormy
night; the rain fell in torrents.

$ awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} 1' RS='[[:space:]]' novel
It
was
a
dark
and
stormy
night
the
rain
fell
in
torrents
```

Or, to save the output in file `words`, use:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} 1' RS='[[:space:]]' novel >words
```

**How it works:**

- `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")`

  This tells awk to find any punctuation and replace it with an empty string.

  `[:punct:]` is a character class that includes all punctuation.  This form includes all punctuation defined by unicode.  Unicode defines, for example, many types of quote characters.  This will include them all.
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-record.
- `RS='[[:space:]]'`

  This tells awk to use any sequence of whitespace as the record separator.  This means that each word defines a separated record and awk will read in one word as a time for processing.

#### Counting the words

The usual approach for counting items in Unix to use `sort` and `uniq -c` as follows:

```
$ echo 'one two two three three three' | awk '{gsub(/^[[:punct:]]|[[:punct:]]$/, "")} 1' RS='[[:space:]]' | sort | uniq -c
      1 one
      3 three
      2 two
```

Alternatively, awk can do it all:

```
$ echo 'one two two three three three' | awk '{gsub(/^[[:punct:]]|[[:punct:]]$/, ""); a[$0]++} END{for (w in a) print w,a[w]}' RS='[[:space:]]'
three 3
two 2
one 1
```

### Alternate awk method

[Andriy Makukha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5407270/andriy-makukha) suggests that we might not want to remove punctuation from within a word like the single quote in `I've`.  Similarly, we might not want to remove the periods from within a URL so that `google.com` stays `google.com`.  To remove punctuation only if it is at the beginning or end of a word, we would replace the `gsub` command with:

```
gsub(/^[[:punct:]]|[[:punct:]]$/, "")
```

For example:

```
$ echo "I've got 'google.com'" | awk '{gsub(/^[[:punct:]]|[[:punct:]]$/, "")} 1' RS='[[:space:]]'
I've
got
google.com
```

## Using sed

This sed command will remove all punctuation and put each word on a separate line:

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g; s/[[:space:]]/\n/g' novel
```

If we run our command on it, we obtain:

```
$ sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g; s/[[:space:]]/\n/g' novel
It
was
a
dark
and
stormy
night
the
rain
fell
in
torrents
```

If you want the words saved in file `words`, then try:

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g; s/[[:space:]]/\n/g' novel >words
```

__How it works:_

- `s/[[:punct:]]//g`

  This tells sed to find any occurrence of punctuation and replace it with nothing.  Again, we use `[:punct:]` because it will handle all the unicode-defined punctuation characters.
- `s/[[:space:]]/\n/g`

  This tells sed to find any sequence of whitespace and replace it with a single newline.

Comment: The problem with this awk solution is that `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")` will remove single quotes also. So instead of `I've` you will get `Ive` in your list of words.

Comment: Hats off, both of you are hitting on all 8 tonight with `awk`.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Interesting.  There are many possible variations on that but I added to the answer one awk approach to handle that type of thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove certain punctuation with awk's `gsub` function:

```
awk '{ 
    gsub(/["*^&()#@$,\.!?~;]/,"")
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {print $i "\t" NR "\n" > "words"}
}' novel
```

You can find more information on this function [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Also, you don't need to use `printf $i "\t" NR "\n", $0` since only the part before comma (the *format*) will be printed in most cases. Therefore I changed it to `print`, dropping the `$0` item.