# Using sort function gives error with the pipe "|"

Tags: sorting, awk

From the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628667/word-count-using-awk)

This

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' testfile | sort -k 2 -n
```

works fine when I enter it from the command line.

But I could not make it work when I try to run it from a command file.

My source file is `voleybol.org`

I enter this into the `command.awk`

```
{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]} | sort sort -k 2 -n
```

Then I run from the command line:

```
awk -f command.awk voleybol.org
```

But this gives the error

```
Syntax error at source line 1 source file command.awk
 context is
    {gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]} >>>  | <<<  sort sort -k 2 -n
awk: bailing out at source line 1 source file command.awk
```

It seems that there is a problem with the pipe. How can I fix this?

Comment: The code from the original answer is a shell solution.  you need to make a bash (or sh) script. First line is `#!/bin/bash`, paste the answer code , save the file, make it executable with `chmod +x myScript.sh`. Then test from there. `awk` will not understand pipes in the context you are using. Good luck.

Comment: I see this pattern in several tutorials `awk -f source-file input-file1 input-file2 …` https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-awk-programming/9781491904930/ch01.html#:~:text=Use%20either%20'%20awk%20'%20program%20',end%20of%20the%20same%20line. Why can't I use this way of running the script? Without making it executable.

Comment: your `command.awk` file contains both `awk` and `shell` code; for `awk -f command.awk` to work you can only place `awk` code in `command.awk`; in this case you'll need to remove the `| sort sort -k 2 -n` from `command.awk`; you could (re)add the `| sort sort -k 2 -n` either on the command line, in a shell script (see shelter's comment), or in a function (a variation on a shell script)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks. This worked fine: `awk -f command.awk voleybol.org | sort -k 2 -n` And this is the `command.awk`: `{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}`

Comment: another option if you're working with `GNU awk` is to look into sorting `awk` arrays (search on `asort()`, `asorti()` and `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`); this would require you store your data in `awk` arrays but then you could do the sorting within your `awk` script (thus eliminating the need for `| sort -k 2 -n`); you'll definitely end up with more `awk` code (vs.  the simple `sort -k 2 -n`) and certainly an increase in memory usage.